# change background color on click react native

Tags: react-native

i want to make my button update its background color from white to blue and when i click again i want to make the background white again. how can is it possible to do this from the stylesheet? if not how can i do this

button:

```
<TouchableOpacity style = {styles.circular}></TouchableOpacity>
```

style:

```
circular:{
    width:15,
    height:15,
    borderColor:'#55bcf6',
    borderRadius:5,
    borderWidth:3,
    backgroundColor:'white'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an onClick attribute, a color state and a dynamic style, something like this:

```js
const [color, setColor] = useState("white");

<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => setColor(color === 'blue' ? 'white' : 'blue')}
    style={{backgroundColor: color}}
>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: how do i set the style to the one you mentioned and keep the default style at the same time

Comment: just give a class to the button and style it from the css file

Comment: I edited all answers by replacing onClick with onPress.

Answer (score 1):

using [] in style

```
const [color, setColor] = useState("white");

 <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => setColor(color==='blue' ? 'white' : 'blue')}
         style={[styles. circular, {backgroundColor: color}]}
 >
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

there you can you change the background Color and apply it with the default

```
const [color, setColor] = useState("white");

 <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => setColor(color==='blue' ? 'white' : 'blue')}
         style={{...styles.circular, backgroundColor: color}}
 >
 </TouchableOpacity>
```